# SQL Server Join Order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I use `SQL Server` and have a query with multiple join.

I want that SQL Server join table A and B in first and then join with table C.

but SQL Server join table B and C in first and then join with table A.

How can I force SQL Server to observe my join order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you dont mind can i ask you why you want that, for any specific reason or just a curiosity? 

P.S Optimizer usually choose the best order to joins table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the query hint `FORCE ORDER`.

From [Query Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

> Specifies that the join order indicated by the query syntax is
>   preserved during query optimization.

Comment: And while that answers the question it generally forces a total misunderstanding how joins work onto the user. -1^.

Comment: Please note that force order also affects multiple selects commonly found in CTE tables using WITH, where selects will be execute from top to buttom

Answer (score 0):

Without force order, a way to do this is nested join as both statements bellow are equal:

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
JOIN B ON B.ID = A.BID
JOIN C ON C.ID = A.CID

SELECT * 
FROM (A JOIN B ON B.ID = A.BID) 
JOIN C ON C.ID = A.CID
```

However this works because all joins are inner (also work for all LEFT OUTER)but it won't always work with combined joins

Answer (score -1):

Joining order is same order you give in select query.

No force logic here, only order which you give and join column condition will filter the data.

If you give primary-key or composite key option in join clause than very good. If you use 2 transaction table and then join with master table , then have a issue.

Always use main or master table first and then add secondary table one by one.

You can check with execution plan.

[image]

Comment: This answer is not correct, but it does have a pretty picture whose source should be acknowledged.